# Issues Compiling Paho MQTT statically in Windows 64 bit

Tags: c++, mqtt, paho

Using the Cmake GUI Ive added the entry to build statically.

Everything works fine whenever I have Code Generation -> Runtime Library set to Multi-threaded DLL (even though options were set to build as static). The samples build fine and work.

In my actual project, which needs to use static lib, it obviously throws linker error 2038 with mismatched RuntimeLibrary.

How can I force paho MQTT to build statically? I'm using visual studio 14 2015 with c++.

Comment: Well, something is wrong and you need to fix the bug. Seriously, there's no checkbox "link without errors" anywhere in the setting, so you will have to either file a bug report (not here but at the project's site) or dive into the code and extract a [mcve].

Comment: Well I guess what I'm curious about is if this is a common issue others have come across. My quick google searches haven't told me too much about this issue.

Comment: Don't search the web at random but the bugtracking system of the involved projects, that's much more likely to turn up useful results.

Comment: I will do that, thank you for the input.